# Eigenvalues of a linear transformation $f(a,b,c) = (-b-c, -2a+b-c, 4a+2b+4c)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm asked to find the eigenvalues of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $f(a,b,c) = (-b-c, -2a+b-c, 4a+2b+4c)$.

Let $B$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

So I found the transformation matrix $A = M(f;B,B) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & -1\\ -2 & 1 & -1\\ 4 & 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$.

After, I found the eigenvalues for $A$, with $|A - \lambda \cdot I_{3}| = 0 \Leftrightarrow -\lambda^{3} + 5 \lambda^{2} - 8\lambda + 4 = 0$. This eigenvalues are not the ones in the book solutions, so I've re-checked the process about 3 times now but I always end up with the same values...

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I was factorizing the characteristic polynomial wrong, and so it ends up being $-\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)^2$ and the values match the solution in the book.

Comment: Typo, now it is corrected

Comment: The eigenvalues are $2,2,1$, with eigenvectors $(-1,0,2), (-1,2,0),(-1,-1,2)$ ([According to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C-1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B4%2C2%2C4%7D%7D)). The textbook is wrong if these are the solutions you obtain.

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial is good. Maybe you did not consider the same $f$ as in the book ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but the f I posted there is the same I have in the book...

Comment: @player3236 those eigenvalues are correct, then the book is right... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: How did you factorize the characteristic polynomial $-\lambda^3+5\lambda^2-8\lambda+4=0$?

Comment: @player3236 It turns out I was factorizing the polynomial wrong.. I just checked online and it is $-\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)^2$